# How to extract only the key-value from this list-dict json response?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I would like how can I extract only the keys and values from this json response:

```
[{u'SkuSellersInformation': [{u'Name': u'site', u'Price': 409, u'IsDefaultSeller': True, u'AvailableQuantity': 2, u'LogoUrl': None, u'SellerId': u'1', u'ListPrice': 409}], u'BestInstallmentNumber': 10, u'RealWeightKg': 100.0, u'NotifyMe': True, u'HasServiceAtCartPage': False, u'RewardValue': 0.0, u'ListPrice': 409, u'Name': u'Light Blue Eau de Toilette Dolce & Gabbana - Perfume Feminino - 50ml', u'HasExtendedWarranty': False, u'BestInstallmentValue': 40.9, u'Ean': u'0737052074313', u'Price': 409, u'RealWidth': 10.0, u'IdProduct': 909, u'AvailabilityMessage': u'True', u'HasServiceAtServicePage': False, u'RealLength': 10.0, u'RealHeight': 10.0, u'HasServiceAtProductPage': False, u'SalesChannel': u'1', u'DefaultSellerId': u'1', u'Reference': u'002796', u'HasExtendedWarrantyPage': False, u'Id': 5293, u'Images': [[{u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-320-320/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 2, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-55-55/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 3, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-65-65/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 1, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-500-500/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 10, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-120-120/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 29, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-130-130/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 30, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}], [{u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-320-320/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 2, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-55-55/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 3, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-65-65/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 1, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-500-500/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 10, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-120-120/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 29, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-130-130/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 30, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}]], u'Availability': True}]
```

I tried this way, but still remain some dicts inside sub-lists

```
import urllib2
import json

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.site.com.br/produto/sku/5293')
data = json.load(response)

for a in data:
    for key, value in a.items():
        print key, value
```

This is the result, but as you guys can see, still remain some key-value inside the sub-list

```
SkuSellersInformation :  [{u'Name': u'site', u'Price': 409, u'IsDefaultSeller': True, u'AvailableQuantity': 2, u'LogoUrl': None, u'SellerId': u'1', u'ListPrice': 409}]
BestInstallmentNumber :  10
RealWeightKg :  100.0
NotifyMe :  True
HasServiceAtCartPage :  False
RewardValue :  0.0
ListPrice :  409
Name :  Light Blue Eau de Toilette Dolce & Gabbana - Perfume Feminino - 50ml
HasExtendedWarranty :  False
BestInstallmentValue :  40.9
Ean :  0737052074313
Price :  409
RealWidth :  10.0
IdProduct :  909
AvailabilityMessage :  True
HasServiceAtServicePage :  False
RealLength :  10.0
RealHeight :  10.0
HasServiceAtProductPage :  False
SalesChannel :  1
DefaultSellerId :  1
Reference :  002796
HasExtendedWarrantyPage :  False
Id :  5293
Images :  [[{u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-320-320/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 2, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-55-55/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 3, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-65-65/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 1, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-500-500/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 10, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-120-120/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 29, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-130-130/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 30, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}], [{u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-320-320/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 2, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-55-55/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 3, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-65-65/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 1, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-500-500/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 10, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-120-120/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 29, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-130-130/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 30, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}]]
Availability :  True
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show the expected output based on the input you provided? Also, more importantly, can you show your own attempt at this with a [mcve]?

Comment: You mean you want to unwrap the data within single dict (not the nested dict)?

Comment: Hi there! I edit my question with the code and the result that I need.

Comment: I still don't understand what you need, it seems to just be the second line to the fifth line of the original output.

Comment: E.g "SkuSellersInformation" has a, lets call, "sub-list" with a dict inside. I need also extract this keys-values. In other words, I need all the json response above, in a simple key: value format.

Comment: Are you trying to make it a flat dictionary?

Comment: Hi there! As you can see, the result mix key-value with some list with dict inside. I dont know what you men with "flat", but I need transform all in a single dict, removing the sub-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JSON allows the definition of recursive data structures, the following recursive function will find all the key, value pairs in all the dictionaries encountered in one. Note it may yield the same key multiple times when it occurs in more than one (nested or parallel) dictionary.

```
def get_all(myjson):
    """ Recursively find the keys and associated values in all the dictionaries
        in the json object or list.
    """
    if isinstance(myjson, dict):
        for jsonkey, jsonvalue in myjson.items():
            if not isinstance(jsonvalue, (dict, list)):
                yield jsonkey, jsonvalue
            else:
                for k, v in get_all(jsonvalue):
                    yield k, v
    elif isinstance(myjson, list):
        for element in myjson:
            if isinstance(element, (dict, list)):
                for k, v in get_all(element):
                    yield k, v

data = [{u'SkuSellersInformation': [{u'Name': u'site', u'Price': 409, u'IsDefaultSeller': True, u'AvailableQuantity': 2, u'LogoUrl': None, u'SellerId': u'1', u'ListPrice': 409}], u'BestInstallmentNumber': 10, u'RealWeightKg': 100.0, u'NotifyMe': True, u'HasServiceAtCartPage': False, u'RewardValue': 0.0, u'ListPrice': 409, u'Name': u'Light Blue Eau de Toilette Dolce & Gabbana - Perfume Feminino - 50ml', u'HasExtendedWarranty': False, u'BestInstallmentValue': 40.9, u'Ean': u'0737052074313', u'Price': 409, u'RealWidth': 10.0, u'IdProduct': 909, u'AvailabilityMessage': u'True', u'HasServiceAtServicePage': False, u'RealLength': 10.0, u'RealHeight': 10.0, u'HasServiceAtProductPage': False, u'SalesChannel': u'1', u'DefaultSellerId': u'1', u'Reference': u'002796', u'HasExtendedWarrantyPage': False, u'Id': 5293, u'Images': [[{u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-320-320/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 2, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-55-55/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 3, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-65-65/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 1, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-500-500/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 10, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-120-120/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 29, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/183280-130-130/light-blue-edt-dg-2.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 30, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'183280', u'IsMain': False}], [{u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-320-320/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 2, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-55-55/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 3, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-65-65/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 1, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-500-500/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 10, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-120-120/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 29, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}, {u'Path': u'http://site.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/187857-130-130/light-blue-eau-de-toilette-dolce-gabbana-perfume-feminino.jpg', u'ArchiveTypeId': 30, u'Name': None, u'IdArchive': u'187857', u'IsMain': True}]], u'Availability': True}]

for key, value in get_all(data):
    print('{!r}: {!r}'.format(key, value))
```

Comment: Hi martineau! Thank you for the code. I made a test, but still returning dicts inside the list

Comment: Try the undated version.

Comment: Thank you very much martineau! That's exactly what I need.

Comment: You're welcome. One thing you didn't consider when asking your question—and why my initial answer didn't do what you want—is that in JSON it's possible for keys to be associated with a dict or list, not just simple values, so just printing the key and value is "wrong" in those cases.

Comment: Actually I'm very new in Python. That's why I dont know such details... Thank you my friend!

Comment: No worries. Knowing that detail is probably more about understanding the [JSON format](http://www.json.org) than being familiar with Python. My philosophy is that making mistakes and asking questions are just part of the leaning process—which is why websites like SO exist. Here's a tip: You can use `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))` to see the structure of the data more clearly.

Comment: Hi martineau! Me again... I'm hours trying to do a little modification, but no luck. Instead return a generator, how can I put ALL the key-value inside a single dict like this: `test = {'RealWeightKg': '100.0', 'Name': 'site', 'Price': 409, 'IsDefaultSeller': True, etc, etc, etc}` Because this way will be much more easy to access the values... Tks!

Comment: It's really unfair to keep expanding the scope of your question by asking so many additional follow-on ones—so this will be my last response. The output could be converted to a dictionary by using a dictionary comprehension: ie `{key: value for key, value in get_all(data)}`. However if there are duplicate keys—and there are in your data—only the last one yielded will be retained, so technically it wouldn't be **all** of them. A workaround for that restriction would be to do something similar, but have each key map to a _list_ of values with one or more items in it.

Answer (score -1):

Well,

Your question is not clear, but maybe, this is what you want:

```
for a in data:
    for key, value in a.items():
        if key in ['BestInstallmentNumber', 'RealWeightKg', 'NotifyMe', 'HasServiceAtCartPage', 'RewardValue']:
            print key, value
```

Comment: Actually I think extracting the dicts from the list can solve the question. Is there a way to do such a thing?