# Iterate Through Text File Searching for a Value?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, file

I want to get the temperature attribute in the text file below using Python. It should return the value 69.08 (in this case).

The very long text file, `weather_data.json`, can be download from [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0y80Pdgk).

This is my current code, but it returns way more than just 69.08:

```
with open("weather_data.json") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for part in line.split():
            if "temperature" in part:
                print part
```

Comment: This is JSON. Please parse it as such

Comment: It is not quite JSON, since it is not closed properly--two closing braces are missing, and the final `"data"` key has no value. Are quite sure, Sunny, that you copied the text file here properly? And did you include all line endings (line feeds and/or carriage returns)?

Comment: You are correct, I have not included the whole file, it is really, really long, but if you think it would help then I can.

Comment: If would be helpful to have the whole file. You can upload it to [pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com) and [edit] your question and add a link to it afterwards.

Comment: The answer to this other [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216533/how-to-extract-only-the-key-value-from-this-list-dict-json-response) might also help.